# Pycharm stopped displaying import errors

Tags: python, pycharm

I was wondering how to get PyCharm to display import errors?

It was previously working for me and now it stopped.  PyCharm still shows other python syntax errors, and will autocomplete. However, there is no red squiggly line shown under unknown references.

[image]

Comment: Have you updated? I think a new version came out recently.

Comment: what do you mean by import errors? Or are we talking about unresolved errors?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes unresolved sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control all of the code inspection errors in the settings.

Go to `File` then `Settings`. Search for `Inspections` in the left pane. In the search area on the right type "Python" to see all inspections for Python. Go down to "Unresolved references" and make sure it is checked to fix your problem.

The following is a screenshot showing how it should look:

[image: Inspection settings]

Comment: did not resolve issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was no problem with the inspections settings.

I tried multiple solution suggested in other question, including resetting the PyCharm to default configurations, and nothing helped.

The only thing that ended up solving this was to delete the `.idea` directory inside the project directory. **This resets the project-specific settings, so make sure you're ok with that!**

1. Take note of any project-specific settings you'd want to reproduce later (for me it was mainly customized Run Configurations)
2. Close PyCharm
3. Go to the project directory and delete the `.idea` sub-directory (I actually simply moved it elsewhere, in case I wanted to undo)
4. Open PyCharm again - you will need to configure the project settings from scratch now